# Compromised Chrome? Modified Content-Security-Policy

Tags: google-chrome, nginx, content-security-policy

My application is being reverse proxied by Nginx.

I've setup Nginx to add a Content-Security-Policy header to the response. This is working perfectly and I can see the header returned from Chrome as well as CURL from a number of machines.

From a particular machine I'm seeing something very strange. Chrome is showing only a small portion of the Content-Security-Policy header was returned in the response, leaving out a number of key policies. When using a different browser on the same machine the headers are all returned.

Apologies if this is a silly question but could it be that a binary or something else in Chrome has been modified and is modifying the Content-Security-Policy header? I understand how ridiculous that sounds and there could be something I don't understand about CSP.

Could someone help me understand what is happening here?

What most machines are getting:

```
Content-Security-Policy:default-src 'self';  script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://assets.zendesk.com https://connect.facebook.net;  img-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://s-static.ak.facebook.com https://assets.zendesk.com;  style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com https://assets.zendesk.com;  font-src 'self' https://themes.googleusercontent.com;  frame-src https://assets.zendesk.com https://www.facebook.com https://s-static.ak.facebook.com https://tautt.zendesk.com;  object-src 'self'
```

What this one particular machine is getting:

```
Content-Security-Policy:default-src 'self';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureka! I have the answer.

It looks like ESET was inspecting and modifying the headers in the request. You can switch this [off quite easily](http://support.eset.com/kb3126/?locale=en_US).